# A word that desribes different ways of teaching a topic

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the a word that describes the teaching approach a teacher/course may take"

So the word that would describe  *Applied*, *Practical*, *Experimental*, *Theoretical* etc. in "Applied Calculus". "Practical Demon-Keeping", "Theoretical Physics", "Applied Chemistry", "Experimental Top-Spinning"...

As always, help is greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Maybe they are ***methodologies***?

Comment: syllabus? rubric?

Comment: Please explain the motivation for the question, and supply at least one example sentence with a blank where the word will go.

Comment: Word is actually used as a label for metadata field for encoding courses.

Comment: To be precise, the word would be a candidate term of art in a taxonomy that I am building. Which is why the "use in a sentence" was a bit difficult to come up with, given that I would be providing a definition of the word :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for ***pedagogy***.

ODO:

> **[pedagogy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pedagogy)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> The method and practice of teaching, especially as an academic subject
>   or theoretical concept.
>
> ‘subject-based pedagogies’
>
> ‘If we approach with that kind of pedagogy, we'll reduce academic
>   dishonesty.’